# Unexpected jtable custom renderer behavior

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My goal is to make a basic pixel art application in Java Swing (I know this is far from ideal, we have to do something with Swing for a class and I thought this sounded kind of fun).

The idea is that the color of any selected cell in the JTable is changed to the color selected in the JComboBox.

Here is what it looks like currently after a click at the highlighted cell (9,7):

[image: After one click at (9,7)]

And after a click elsewhere (such as at (0,6) shown), it tends to fill in the space in between the two spaces, as well as the remainder of the rows as well.

[image: After a second click at (0,6)]

This of course is not ideal - I want only one cell to change color per click. I am new to custom JTable rendering so I have attached the necessary code in the hopes that someone can help me spot my error. The area of interest is toward the bottom when I create the JTable the CustomModel class.

```
//Lots of importing

public class PixelArtistGUI extends JFrame {

String colors[] = { "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Magenta", "Black", "White" };
JComboBox colorList = new JComboBox(colors);

public PixelArtistGUI() {
    setTitle("PixelArtist");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 450));

    // Content Pane

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 125, 125, 125 };
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[] {360, 15};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    JLabel colorSelect = new JLabel("Select Color:");
    colorSelect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    colorSelect.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_colorSelect = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_colorSelect.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc_colorSelect.gridx = 0;
    gbc_colorSelect.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    gbc_colorSelect.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_colorSelect.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(colorSelect, gbc_colorSelect);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_colorList = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_colorList.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    gbc_colorList.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_colorList.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc_colorList.gridx = 1;
    gbc_colorList.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(colorList, gbc_colorList);

    JButton screenshotButton = new JButton("Save Screenshot");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_screenshotButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_screenshotButton.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    gbc_screenshotButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_screenshotButton.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
    gbc_screenshotButton.gridx = 2;
    gbc_screenshotButton.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(screenshotButton, gbc_screenshotButton);

    String[] colHeadings = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
    int numRows = 16;
    PixelModel model = new PixelModel(numRows, colHeadings.length);
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeadings);

    JTable table_1 = new JTable(model);
    table_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    table_1.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table_1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomModel());

    GridBagConstraints gbc_table_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_table_1.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc_table_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_table_1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_table_1.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(table_1, gbc_table_1);
    table_1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table_1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table_1.setRowHeight(23);

    this.pack();
}

// Custom table renderer to change cell colors
public class CustomModel extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
                column);
        Color c;
        try {
            String cString = colorList.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase();
            Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(cString);
            c = (Color) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c = null;
        }

        if (isSelected)
            label.setBackground(c);
        return label;
    }
}

// Custom table model to make the cells selectable but not editable
public class PixelModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    PixelModel(int numRows, int numColumns) {
        super(numRows, numColumns);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any tips, I am stuck on how to fix this.

Comment: You should be storing the color value in the TableModel, then your renderer should render the value of the cell

Comment: I don't see any reason to use reflection.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how your interval selection should work. When you click on a cell, what other cells do you expect to be colored?

Comment: If I have "red" selected, I want just the cell that I click on to turn, and stay, red until it is clicked again with another color selected. But it is currently changing the color of entire rows when I click a cell.

Comment: O.K., the `SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` suggested otherwise, but I understand now what you want.

Comment: Oh you are right I probably don't want that. Is my problem in the selection type, and is there a way I can make it so that only one cell can be clicked, instead of a row like in `SINGLE_SELECTION`? It exhibits the same behavior shown with `SINGLE_SELECTION`.

Comment: Do you have to do it through the cell renderer?

Comment: I've been searching around for a few hours before posting and that's all I've seen people do but I don't see a way to keep it colored when it is no longer selected.

Comment: It's because the color is set for the renderer itself *and* the label, and when the renderer is called upon to paint a cell, it remembers the previous color setting and colors all the cells it needs to paint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) for more details about how renderers and editors actually work.

Each time `getTableCellRendererComponent` is called, you are expected to completely configure the renderer based on the value and state of the cell.  So basically, what you're doing, is simply setting the background color once and never change it for any other condition, meaning when any other cell is painted (for whatever reason), it's still using the same background color.

Instead, you should be using the value stored in the `TableModel` to make decisions about what the cell should be painting.  To accomplish this, you'll probably need a simple `CellEditor` which can simply return the currently selected color

Maybe something like...

[image: Pixel]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class PixelArtistGUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                PixelArtistGUI frame = new PixelArtistGUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    String colors[] = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Magenta", "Black", "White"};
    JComboBox colorList = new JComboBox(colors);

    public PixelArtistGUI() {
        setTitle("PixelArtist");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 450));

        // Content Pane
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{125, 125, 125};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{360, 15};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel colorSelect = new JLabel("Select Color:");
        colorSelect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        colorSelect.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_colorSelect = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_colorSelect.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc_colorSelect.gridx = 0;
        gbc_colorSelect.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc_colorSelect.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_colorSelect.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(colorSelect, gbc_colorSelect);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_colorList = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_colorList.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc_colorList.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_colorList.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc_colorList.gridx = 1;
        gbc_colorList.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(colorList, gbc_colorList);

        JButton screenshotButton = new JButton("Save Screenshot");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_screenshotButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_screenshotButton.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc_screenshotButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_screenshotButton.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc_screenshotButton.gridx = 2;
        gbc_screenshotButton.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(screenshotButton, gbc_screenshotButton);

        String[] colHeadings = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
        int numRows = 16;
        PixelModel model = new PixelModel(numRows, colHeadings.length);
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeadings);

        JTable table_1 = new JTable(model);
        table_1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                TableCellEditor editor = table_1.getCellEditor();
                if (editor != null) {
                    if (editor.stopCellEditing()) {
                        editor.cancelCellEditing();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        table_1.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table_1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomRenderer());
        table_1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new CustomEditor());

        GridBagConstraints gbc_table_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_table_1.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_table_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_table_1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_table_1.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(table_1, gbc_table_1);
        table_1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table_1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table_1.setRowHeight(23);

        this.pack();
    }

    public class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, null, false, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (value != null && value instanceof Color) {
                setBackground((Color) value);
            } else {
                setBackground(null);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class CustomEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private JPanel panel;

        public CustomEditor() {
            this.panel = new JPanel();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            Color c = null;
            try {
                String cString = colorList.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase();
                Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(cString);
                c = (Color) field.get(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                c = null;
            }
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            panel.setBackground((Color) getCellEditorValue());
            return panel;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    // Custom table model to make the cells selectable but not editable
    public class PixelModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        PixelModel(int numRows, int numColumns) {
            super(numRows, numColumns);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Now, before anyone jumps on me. I would fill the `JComboBox` with `Color`s and use a custom `ListCellRenderer` to display it.

Comment: @user1803551 Not sure I know what you mean, it seems to work just fine for me

Comment: Yeah tripped over that myself :{

Comment: BTW, what do you use to create the `gif`?

Comment: Will come in handy :)

Comment: WOW that does it beautifully - Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm all for MCVE's, but to shorten them I tend to collapse imports to shorten the snippets a bit (`import java.awt.*; ...`).

Comment: @TT. But here, I don't get responses about mismatched classes, like Timer and Date